# Moving documents from one document library to another with SharePoint 2013 Workflow using list item information

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

To preface: I believe this may be impossible with OOTB solutions and if it is I have a plan B, but this plan would be much easier to implement if it is indeed possible.

Is there any way to create a SharePoint workflow that moves a file from a separate document library to another separate library?

The workflow is launched when a new item is created in a list. The item contains the information needed to find the document that it's referencing (ID, path, folder path, name etc...). Is it possible to take this information and then move the file being referenced to another library using a SharePoint workflow?

The document can't be simply copied because version history must stay with the document. I'm also unable to run the workflow in the library that contains the document because it's deciding on what documents to move based on the last modified date and as soon as the document is touched by the workflow it's been modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to copy files with metadata, we can use the OOTB workflow to achieve it.

If you want to copy files with version history, please check the Nintex workflow.

[Nintex Workflow Move Document and Preserve Version History](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ss-j-AoBtpw)

Or we can create event receiver with custom code to achieve it.

[Copy files between libraries by keeping versions](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2dae720b-58a8-4220-80b2-46948be3e233/copy-files-between-libraries-by-keeping-versions?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, seeing as there seems to be no OOTB solution I went ahead and started writing a Powershell script to do what I need instead.